# Basic troubleshooting for tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

This is an idea to dispell with the first few comments on many questions being a few basic troubleshooting steps to aid the prospective answerers.

Would it be possible to attach a "Basic Troubleshooting" list to tags. Similar to the description.

Not every tag would have this, and it would only be editable in the same way other tags attributes are. (I'm not sure what the authorization is for that).

When asking a question, someone adds a tag and the "Basic Troubleshooting Tips" shows up under the `Tags` input box.

Just an idea, maybe it been mentioned and shot down before.

Comment: You can add such information to tag wikis. More popular ones, like [java](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info), already have a list of FAQs attached.

Comment: But nothing directs to that when you tag a question with `java`. Even a link that pops saying "Have you tried these debugging steps" would be cool. But who would actually follow it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting idea, but I see one big problem with it: (most) users won't read it.

There is a huge amount of information on the "ask question" page already, and the deluge of poorly written questions we get makes clear that people aren't reading what's already there. For example:

- As illustrated in the question [Beware, all ye who `enter code here`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295509/beware-all-ye-who-enter-code-here), people routinely fail to read/analyze/notice the question preview, even though it occupies almost all of the space between the text editor and the submission button.
- Countless more questions per day fail the "did you look at the `Questions that may already have your answer` section" test.
- Half (almost all?) of the simple debugging questions we might answer in such a hint are things like "what's the difference between `i++` and `++i`" or "why doesn't this `while (true)` loop ever end?" Every single one of those questions could be answered on the first page of Google's search results for any terms even slightly related to the question.
- And, of course, almost nobody reads [any of the highly-relevant help section documents on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

In addition, as @approxiblue said in the comments, popular tags like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) already have lots of helpful information on basic debugging.

In other words, yes, a list of answers to common problems would be helpful... and that's why we have the "Questions that may already have your answer" section. Adding more text to the "ask question" page will not solve the problem of people not reading. You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.