# Why are there so many incorrectly inserted images on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, images

Why are there so many incorrectly inserted images on Stack Overflow?
They should be inserted like this:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

But yesterday and today I have fixed a number of posts which had:

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

The moderators accepted my edits; they looked obviously wrong to me before I fixed them.
A search for "image description here" https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22image+description+here%22 shows over 8,000 results.
Is there some OS or browser inserting the markup incorrectly?

Comment: Low rep users cannot post inline images (to avoid spam I guess).

Comment: Actually, `[enter image description here][1]` is a valid image reference in Markdown, as long as there is a URL at `[1]`. It might just be @CodyGray not cleaning up well :P. Obviously, it would be nice if people actually edited that text, but there are plenty of images out there on the internet that don't have good `alt` attributes either...

Comment: OK I understand better now low rep users cant post inline images. But couldn't the text read "View image" or something instead for these users? Having links with text "enter image description here" was confusing.

Comment: And should users with high enough rep edit these posts to put the images inline where they are appropriately sized?

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295509/792066

Comment: **Do not** edit images to inline them into the post unless they are **absolutely** necessary. Probably 99% of uses are totally inappropriate - screenshots of code or error messages that should be posted as text. Either transcribe the text or leave it alone.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I disagree. It is better to have the information in the post than not at all. The OP should then be prompted to replace the image with text if appropriate, but then they will at least have been trained not to insert _broken_ images.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. [**This is how the image upload tool inserts images for new users**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129833/warn-new-users-earlier-that-they-cannot-post-links-or-images/267491#267491)

   On some sites, where images are considered *critical* to being able to ask a good question, new users are allowed to insert them normally. On sites like Stack Overflow, where the cost of having to wade through a bunch of porn isn't worth the advantage of new users being able to post inline images of their code, the upload tool just inserts a link.
2. **Folks are, as a rule, really really lazy.** That boilerplate text is supposed to encourage people to enter some descriptive information, so that folks using screen-readers can have some idea of what's there. But an awful lot of people just leave it, because they're lazy jerks.

Comment: Follow-up suggestion: change the boilerplate text to "I am a lazy jerk".

Comment: I have actually seen a case where a user with > 2k rep edited a post to turn `[![][1]][1]` into `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

Comment: @TinyGiant Are you sure they hadn't just deleted the image and used to uploader to move it to Imgur? That's pretty common, and would still use `[1]` because the old link would get auto-removed since it's not used in the post anymore. I can't imagine why anyone would intentionally type that text into the image Markdown without having done something else with the image and just... not changed the description back.

Comment: @animuson the image was formatted as an image before the edit. I can't remember the exact post now, but I can sure remember scratching my head about it.

Comment: @TinyGiant What I meant is that commonly when that happens, the image is linked from another site (not Imgur). Users frequently re-upload the image onto Imgur so that it's not an external link anymore, and thus not susceptible to link rot. When re-uploading, the Markdown for the image will have been added back by the uploader.

Comment: @animuson Ahh, that could explain it. I don't recall the link section being changed, but it very well could have.

Comment: I really wish I could change the boilerplate text to "resulting plot" since that is what I always change this to. I'm conscious of the visually impaired, but the main reason why are started programming is that I'm lazy.

Comment: I hardly ever enter anything into an image description. If I haven't described the image well enough in the text surrounding it, I've done something wrong. I expect the code to remove the description if I haven't entered anything, if it doesn't I consider it a bug.

Comment: You might also change it to something like "enter image description here for people using screen-readers". I, for example, just recently learned about that.

Comment: So you linked to a post by bluefeet that has "boilerplate text" as the image descriptions, and then proceed to call her a lazy jerk. Wow, that is a new low. ;)

Comment: Not really *new*, @Travis

Answer (score 10):

> They should be inserted like this:
>
> ```
> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
> ```

They should *not* be inserted like that: it makes the post's source ugly and annoying to edit, and creates a clickable link for no good reason.

But that's how they're created by the image uploader button.

If you're going to edit image links, at least take the time to *remove* that "enter image description" template. Ideally, *add* an actual description.

If all you're changing is the clickability of the image, that's terrible use of reviewer's time. A bot could do that if it was necessary.