# enter image description here... please?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images

Would it be feasible to prevent users that haven't filled out the description of a linked images from submitting, instead showing some form of validation error?

Here is an example of the situation I'm talking about [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzFFW.png). Here is [another one.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47824982/1)

Please note that I am talking about the generated links that occur for low rep users who cannot yet embed images - this question has nothing to do with `alt` text on an embedding images.

Ideally said error should be friendly enough, but still force the user to fix the placeholder text. Or perhaps when adding an image, a specific input box should be introduced for entering the image's description?

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295509/beware-all-ye-who-enter-code-here) addresses the same problem, but for `enter code here` rather than the image equivalent. Although I find this occurrence significantly less often, if we implement a blocked for one I would imagine that adding it for the other should be reasonable...

We wouldn't want to block posts that explicitly require those words, so maybe sneaking a unicode character in there or something to ensure we're detecting the placeholder text isn't a bad idea. There might be a better way to achieve this though.

That said, I suspect this is treating a symptom rather than the real problem. It would appear that many users don't bother to look at the preview of their entry (ie, questions and answers alike) before hitting submit or, to be honest, even after. But that's for another question...

Comment: Yes please! I have several times suggested we should add more filters on posts. It's not really a radical idea, given that we have a couple of mandatory filters on the title already. We could make them optional to start with (just a dismissible message) to reduce the number of posts needing repair by editors, and then try to make them mandatory at some point in the future.

Comment: Your last para is a very good point, and I am not sure I understand the phenomenon. I think the preview feature is impossible to ignore, and yet I often see code left in a half-indented state (so the poster clearly knows the formatting tools are there). Is it laziness, or is it because they have limited English and they find the labels on editing controls (and their purpose) to be not as obvious as native speakers? It is hard to fathom.

Comment: @halfer: Truly, it is. Call it OCD if you like, but I can't bring myself to post anything (even on social media or text messages) without rereading what will be posted. Clearly this isn't a common trait though... And I don't consider limited English to be an excuse for seeing fragments of (usually) their own code being in code blocks, and the rest dangling outside of them...

Comment: @halfer It is easy to ignore the preview feature when it is off the bottom of the screen and you need to scroll the view to see it.  With some of my longer answers I need to scroll the view between the answer I'm entering and the bottom of the preview to see how what I'm typing will appear.  Some people may not even realize it is there.  (And there have been times when I would like to see a preview of my comments.)

Comment: @1201: ah, fair enough. That reminds me that I was pondering a feature request that responsively moves the preview to the right-hand side of the editor for wide screens, so that more of it would be visible when editing. Nevertheless I am probably not minded to regard this as the primary reason in the cases Shadow is referencing - when people can't cope with placeholders and simple edit tools despite wanting to be programmers, I suspect a generally sloppy approach is sometimes a factor.

Comment: [next level _enter image description here_](http://prntscr.com/hnenzn)

Comment: Why isn't it a thing yet?